# What are the minimum OCLL/PLL with ZZ method

Tags: rubiks-cube, speedsolving

I've seen on many sites the information that the LL on ZZ need a minimum of 6 OCLL and 14 PLL. But since the OCLL totals 7, and the PLL totals 21, I don't know which ones are "missing".

Is it the case that some of the LL are impossible to happen on ZZ?

Comment: Can you give us a reference for "many sites"?  Some of us might be familiar with what you're talking about, but some of us might not.

Comment: @LeppyR64 this explicitly mentions it http://cube.crider.co.uk/zz.php?p=ll and this one tells the lower limit if LL algs being 20: https://www.speedsolving.com/wiki/index.php/ZZ_Method . I'm pretty sure I've seen it somewhere else, but it might be just information being replicated.

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason they write '6 OCLL' is by considering `sune` and `anti-sune` a single algorithm, for these are mirror cases.
Same for PLLs: `u, a, g(a), g(b) j, n, r,` all have mirror cases, and those mirror cases can be easily solved on the other side with the same algorithm, *mirrored*.